# Establishing communication (HTTP protocol) between multiple ESP8266s to one ESP8266 using STM32

Tags: http, stm32, esp8266

I have been trying to establish a network of ESP8266 (Specifically ESP-01). However, I am not able to find any documentation or anything related on how to actually communicate using HTTP GET and POST methods since I only need a temporary short time communication between multiple sending Nodes to one main Aggregator node.

I don't want to use any Arduino-related libraries as I'm working with STM32. However, I have seen some Arduino-based libraries related to this like ESPAsyncWebServer. But I am not able to find any AT-commands inside it and it's too complicated and intricate for me to understand.

I am basically making a custom library in short so how is communication using HTTP is done between 2 ESPs either using AT commands or any other way (I am going to be communicating to the ESP modules using a dedicated microcontroller through UART) or better if there's any other better way for implementing multiple to 1 connection on ESP. How can I establish this communication to basically send and receive numbers and characters.

Comment: you can use my WiFiEspAT library available in Arduino Library Manager. It requires AT firmware 1.7.4. please read the README